# Need to sample-testing a calendar application against invalid dates

Tags: validation, date, calendar

I am testing a calendar application, which allows a user to select day, month and year, but the problem is the developers have not implemented any form of date validations, which means every month can have up to 31 days.

- The year dropdown menu has a range from `1900 to 2016`,
- the month dropdown menu has Jan, `Feb ... Dec`,
- the day dropdown menu always has `1~31`, regardless of which month I choose.

The testing strategy I am thinking of is:

- choose one non-leap year and test against `29th Feb`; expected to **fail**
- choose one non-leap year and test against `31st April`; expected to **fail**
- choose one leap year and test against `29th Feb`; expected to **succeed**
- choose one leap year and test against `31st April`; expected to **fail**

Four scenarios above should provide a good coverage regarding leap years and invalid dates.

What are your opinions? Am I missing anything?

Comment: A lot depends on what language you are using and if it has some built in support for date validations/throws exceptions if they fail, etc .

Comment: @paisanco, thanks, using Java. Am looking into Java calendar modules.